# Por que me salen caracteres raros cuando concateno la fecha al nombre de un reporte generado por reportviewer

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Estoy tratando de cambiar el nombre de un reporte que se genera con reportviewer, pero al adjuntarle la fecha del sistema los / me salen con caracteres raros, alguien me puede ayudar?

[image: Asi trato de poner la fecha]

[image: asi me sale al momento de generar el reporte y tratar de guardalo]

Comment: Entiendo que es una aplicación asp.net y que el error te da al enviar el excel?

Comment: si así es, genero el reporte en asp.net y cuando quiero exportar dicho reporte a excel me genera ese error

Comment: Pues revisa la respuesta que te han dado. Los "caracteres raros" son `/` y `:` url codificados (`%2F` y `%3A`). Yo te recomendaría no usarlos. Si no, es posible decodificarlos pero para eso haría falta ver el código en el que envias el excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me imagino que es porque la fecha contiene caracteres no válidos para un nombre de archivo.
Necesitarias cambiarlo a por ejemplo YYYYMMDD , por ejemplo el 25 de agosto de 2018 se mostraría como 20180825.. y asi el nombre de tu archivo seria xxxxSoftware 20180825.
En código sería algo así como:

```
 DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd").
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda me sirvio mucho, solo  que en mi caso tuvo que ser así  DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), ya que si no  me salio mal la fecha.

Comment: No tiene nada que ver el nombre del archivo, simplemente se ha aplicado URLEncode es decir se codifica como URL, lo cual convierte los "/" en "%2F" y los ":" en "%3A". Pruebalo en [UrlEncode.org](https://urlencode.org/?text=01%2F02%2F2003+04%3A05%3A06)